# Почему не правильно работает прозрачность в моём коде?

Tags: android, opengl

По задумке сначала первым треугольником указывается видимая область, второй треугольник рисуется больше этой области, но отображаться должна только область отмеченная первым треугольником, у меня же рисуется весь треугольник. Аналогичный код на c++ под windows прекрасно работает.

```
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.ByteOrder;
import java.nio.FloatBuffer;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.microedition.khronos.egl.EGLConfig;
import javax.microedition.khronos.opengles.GL10;

import android.opengl.GLES20;
import android.opengl.GLSurfaceView;
import android.opengl.GLU;

public class HelloOpenGLES20Renderer implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer {

    FloatBuffer triangleBufferA;
    FloatBuffer triangleBufferB;

    float [] triangleA = {
            0, 0, 0,  // A
            1, 0, 0,  // B
            0, 1, 0   // C
        };

    float [] triangleB = {
            0, 0, 0,  // A
            2, 0, 0,  // B
            0,2, 0   // C
        };

    public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) {
        gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_BLEND);
        gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D);

        ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(36);
        bb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        triangleBufferA = bb.asFloatBuffer();
        triangleBufferA.put(triangleA);
        triangleBufferA.position(0);

        ByteBuffer cc = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(36);
        cc.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        triangleBufferB = cc.asFloatBuffer();
        triangleBufferB.put(triangleB);
        triangleBufferB.position(0);   
    }

    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {

        gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);
        gl.glLoadIdentity();
        gl.glTranslatef(0, 0, -2.0f);

        gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);

        gl.glBlendFunc(GL10.GL_ONE, GL10.GL_ONE);

        // задаём видимую область
        gl.glColor4f(1, 1, 1, 1.0f);     
        gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, triangleBufferA);
        gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);

        gl.glBlendFunc(GL10.GL_DST_ALPHA, GL10.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

        // рисуем фигуру
        gl.glColor4f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);     
        gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, triangleBufferB);
        gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);

        gl.glFinish();
    }

    public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {
        gl.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);

        float ratio = (float) width / height;
        gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION);
        gl.glLoadIdentity();
        gl.glFrustumf(-ratio, ratio, -1, 1, 1, 10);
    }  
}
```

Comment: Как вы решили, что просто отрисовка 1 треугольника "задаёт видимую область"? OpenGL *так* не работает.